# javascript array length is 1

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

I am using javascript for creating a filter. I am using ajax and collecting value. 
Ajax Request:

```
if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
vendreq=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{
vendreq=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

vendreq.onreadystatechange=function () { 
 /*  if(b==0){
                document.getElementById("details2").innerHTML="Select GIT more than 0";
            } */
      if((vendreq.readyState==4) && (vendreq.status==200)) {
            venda= [];

            venda.push(vendreq.responseText);
            alert(venda.length);

   } }
vendreq.open("Get","Vendor","true");
vendreq.send();   
});
```

Servlet Vendor:

```
ResultSet rs =ps.executeQuery();    
                 while(rs.next()){
                 out.println(rs.getString("VNAME")+",");
                  out.println(rs.getString("VCODE")+",");
                 }
```

when I display i.e alert(venda) it displays multiple values. where as when I check for the array length , it shows one. Can any one tell me what is the reason for this?

filter:

```
<div class="optionsDiv2" style="display:inline;">     
    Filter by Vendor <select name="item" id="vendor">
        vendb=document.getElementsByName("venda");
     while(vendb.length) { 
     <option>vendb</option>

     }
        </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Because you are pushing a single string in the array! BTW what is the response string you are getting after AJAX?

Comment: Thanks for response @SaurabhSharma. I am getting Name of all vendors and vendor code separated by comma. Can you suggest bme any better way to return the value. I will also prefer to save vendor code in separate array if its possible to directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per I understand from your response text template, you are receiving values like:

```
VNAME1,
VCODE1,
VNAME2,
VCODE2,
...
VNAME(N),
VCODE(N),
```

It would be great if you save result in an object and then return it in the form of json.

It would look similar to:

```
"VALUES":[{
    "VNAME": "VNAME1",
    "VCODE": "VCODE1"
}, {
    "VNAME": "VNAME2",
    "VCODE": "VCODE2"
},
... {
    "VNAME": "VNAME(N)",
    "VCODE": "VCODE(N)"
}]
```

Also for your current situation (As you are returning a plain string) I would suggest you to use a unique splitter for string to create an array

```
out.println(rs.getString("VNAME")+",");
out.println(rs.getString("VCODE")+"+++");
```

So it'll return string as:

```
VNAME1,
VCODE1+++
VNAME2,
VCODE2+++
```

Now remove `venda= [];` and instead of `venda.push(vendreq.responseText);` use `venda = vendreq.responseText.split("+++");`  That'll create an array of your returned string as `"VNAME1,VCODE1","VNAME2,VCODE2"...`

> And trust me its a bad implementation method. Use JSON instead.

Added snippet for example:

```js
str="VNAME1,VCODE1+++VNAME2,VCODE2+++VNAME3,VCODE3+++";
venda=str.split("+++");
alert(venda.length-1 +" Values: "+venda);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I will let you know the result once it is implemented and will also check for the better way to implement using JSON.